# Java EE -- Configuration issues for a beginner

Tags: java, java-ee-6

all. Relative rookie here who has spent the better part of three days just trying to get started with Java EE, and it's driving me up a wall. I've already read through numerous tutorials and consulted several book, so now I am turning to you.

I am starting from complete scratch, having uninstalled NetBeans and Glassfish and the Java EE SDK. My main issue is quite simply configuration. All the resources I've found typically say in a mere throwaway line: "Once you download the SDK, you must configure your environment for Java EE." But HOW? I need it in plain English. Even the most novice guides leave this basic stuff out. Does this mean editing the JAVA_HOME path or what? How does this configuration relate to the Java SE already on my system? Furthermore, I assume I don't need to also download the JDK with EE since I already have a JDK? (I am a Mac user, if that matters.)

I know I have a long, long way to go, so I appreciate any help I can get as I try to get this ball rolling. Much thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you open to using Eclipse instead of NetBeans?

Comment: I'm certainly open it. Several tutorials I was reviewing via Oracle were based on using NetBeans. Wanna make your pitch, Jeff, for Eclipse over NetBeans? :o)

Comment: The thing with Netbeans is it comes with a lot of stuff that is integrated in it and seemingly makes ur life easier. In reality though it can make your life very difficult. For example Netbeans comes with a built in ANT (something used as a build tool)But if you created a jar using the simple preinstalled ANT build in NetBEans then it maybe a problem if someone tries to redo the same thing using a different version of Netbeans that has a version of ANT that doesnt recognize some features of your versioN!With Eclipse you have more control over everything and you can add whatever you need

Comment: @jeremygburton I mentioned Eclipse because it seems like 90% of the JEE developers that post stuff online are using Eclipse, and I would recommend you go with what more people are using so you can benefit from the wealth of information and tutorials!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you would want to set the Java Home path so when you are compiling and running code your JDK is recognized. Sometimes IDEs come with their own JDK and then it really does not matter. However here is how you would set the path in different OS.

http://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

For MAC I recommend this tutorial

http://lindaocta.com/?p=38

Comment: Thanks! But now here is something else I don't get, taking it back a step further: Oracle gives the option of downloading the Java EE SDK with or without the JDK. Since Macs come already with a JDK for Java SE, I don't need to download another one for EE, do I? (I'm not sure Oracle even gives Mac users that option.)

Comment: @jeremygburton, I am not MAC expert, but by default you get only JRE not SDK. We need SDK also for JAVA EE applications.

Comment: @jeremygburton Sorry for the late reply I was out for lunch. Yes you are right you dont need to download any JDK for Mac since it comes with one. All you need is the IDE Netbeans or Eclipse and you are all set. You can type javac in the command line to check if its present.If you are a MAC user dont download anything from Oracle(its already in your comp).

Comment: to add to my comment I see that there might be a confusion that you might need a separate JDK for EE. The answer is NO. What you already have should suffice

Comment: Remember EE is a set of APIs/Interfaces that are added additionally to SE.You can use the JDK to build this provided you have the additional APIS(which you should have with your Netbeans or Eclipse). Normally for EE you need a Web Container also (Again if you are using Netbeans you should have this in the form of Glassfish). Hope its clearer to you now

Comment: Wow. That makes so much more sense. Why doesn't anyone just say amid the jargon, "EE is just another set of APIs"?

Comment: And let me get this straight, but because (again) nobody just spells it out for beginners: If I download NetBeans and Glassfish comes with it, then the EE APIs come **with** Glassfish and I do not need any other SDK or similar download? Do I finally have this right?

Comment: @jeremygburton yup you are right. EE APIs come with Netbeans. If this answer resolved answered all your questions please mark it as an acceptable answer so we can close the discussion :) Feel free to ask me any other questions you have in mind

Comment: Also you are right about how this is not mentioned anywhere. Oracle isnt very clear on documenting this or anything else. Like the fact that JDK 1.5 is Java 5 and keeps leaving people confused if they are one and the same thing. You cannot believe how many resumes I see of developers claiming they used Java 6 with JDK 1.5 for their project

Comment: Done and done. Again, a BIG thank you for your replies (and your patience)!

Comment: No problem. Its been a pleasure

Answer (score 1):

I think if you are using Netbeans then you don't have to worry about these things....

Simply `File > New Project > Java Web > Web Application` will help you get started with web applications..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your JAVA_HOME is set in environment variables (just downloading SDK is not enough, you need to setup), I don't know how to do it mac, but in windows we setup my right click mycomputer-->Advanced-->Environment variables

Then install Netbeans, this step automatically searches for JAVA_HOME and assumes that SDK for all purposes. Then you are all set of programming.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But what should the JAVA_HOME path be set to exactly? When I downloaded the EE SDK before, it created a glassfish directory that doesn't make it at all clear where the path should go.

Comment: You will see, java folder and inside it, JDK and JRE folders, point JAVA_HOME to java folder.

Comment: Java Home path for MAC is /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home Basically when you are running or compiling java classes it needs to find where in your OS the JDK is present. Like when you are trying to open a Zip file you need to tell the file where WinZIp is present in your computer. By setting the JAVA_HOME path you are telling the computer where your JDK is installed that will compile and run your java files!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind switching to Eclipse can I recomend this tutorial [An Eclipse / GlassFish / Java EE 6 Tutorial](http://programming.manessinger.com/tutorials/an-eclipse-glassfish-java-ee-6-tutorial/) ignore the referance to Azzyzt tools and run through the tutorial step by step using [GlassFish Tools Bundle for Eclipse](http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/glassfish/eclipse/).